# jqplot line chart display yaxis 0 at top

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I am using jqplot line chart.

Normally yaxis start with 0 (at bottom) and end with 10 (at top) (example).

Now I need to display start with 10 (at bottom) and end with 0 (at top).

How to config it.